# Only apply CONCAT to Names >25 characters

Tags: sql

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

*Here's what I'm looking to do –*
I'd like to only apply the CONCAT function to the release_names that are <25 characters. Right now, CONCAT + LEFT are being applied to all release name's regardless of the character limit.

```
SELECT
release_name AS full_release_name,
CONCAT('"', LEFT(release_name, 25), '...','"') AS short_release_name
FROM 
release_info
```

*This is the results of the above query–*

| full_release_name | short_release_name |
| --- | --- |
| Come Together - Back to the Oldskool | "Come Together - Back to t..." |
| We'll Pick up the Pieces Next Time | "We'll Pick up the Pieces..." |
| Winter Nights | "Winter Nights..." |
| My Greatest Hits | "My Greatest Hits..." |

*This is the result I'm looking for–*

| full_release_name | short_release_name |
| --- | --- |
| Come Together - Back to the Oldskool | "Come Together - Back to t..." |
| We'll Pick up the Pieces Next Time | "We'll Pick up the Pieces..." |
| Winter Nights | "Winter Nights" |
| My Greatest Hits | "My Greatest Hits" |

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: Added some more info!

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `case` expression.  I am guessing you want to *keep* all names that are 25 characters or less.  And that you want the `CONCAT()` on the *longer* names:

```
(CASE WHEN LEN(release_name) > 25 
      THEN CONCAT('"', LEFT(release_name, 25), '...', '"')
      ELSE release_name
 END) as short_release_name
```

Note:  You don't specify the database.  Some databases use `LENGTH()` rather than `LEN()`.

Comment: This is perfect - it worked! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon!

*For MySQL this is what did it–*

```
(CASE WHEN LENGTH(release_name) > 25 
      THEN CONCAT('"', LEFT(release_name, 25), '...', '"')
      ELSE CONCAT('"',release_name, '...','"')
 END) as short_release_name
```